# Conditional jinja2 ipaddr filter in ansible task

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to apply a task to hosts based on ip block so I've got this.

```
- name: Conditional task
  debug: msg="{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | ipaddr('192.168.1.0/24') | length > 0 }}"
  when: { ansible_all_ip4_addresses | ipaddr('192.168.1.0/24') | length > 0 }
```

The debug statement is working as expected, returning the correct value for each host, but the condition is not working, it gets executed in all hosts. If I remove the brackets in the when clause, then I get

```
 ERROR! error while evaluating conditional
```

I've tried to define a fact with:

```
    - set_fact:
      local: "{{ ansible_all_ip4_addresses | ipaddr('192.168.1.0/24') | length > 0 }}"
```

But instead I get

```
 ERROR! One or more undefined variables: 'ansible_all_ip4_addresses' is undefined
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a typo there. `ansible_all_ip4_addresses` has to be `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses`, the `v` before `4` is  missing.

Apart from that it would work with none or 2 curly brackets, but not with one:

```
when: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | ipaddr('192.168.1.0/24') | length > 0
```

or

```
when: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | ipaddr('192.168.1.0/24') | length > 0 }}"
```